# Where is the principal branch of f(z) = $z^z$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where is the principal branch of f(z) = $z^z$ analytic?

Not sure if this is right but this is my attempt at getting the principal branch:

$e^{\log(z^z)} = e^{z\log(z)} = e^{z(\log|z| + i\arg(z))} = e^{z(\log(r) + i\arg(z))} $

Comment: Dude, how many times others have to correct your posts? Do you have some kinda allergy for dollar signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: by definition $a^b = e^{b \log a}$, for any branch of log.  For principal branch of $a^b$, use the principal branch of log.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log(z)$ can be defined with a branch cut along the negative real axis, we can define
$$
z^z=e^{z\log(z)}
$$
with the same branch cut.